# Bi-dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am currently writing a function which uses a bi-dimensional array of pointers to a structure `cell`. I'll have to update each `cell` with data read in a file.
As I will need to access the various cells, I have to deal with dynamic allocation. But what is the best way to use it here, as I don't need access to the array itself ? Can I use:

```
cell *p_cell[height][width] = malloc(height*width*sizeof(cell*));
```

Or:

```
cell *p_cell[height][width];
```

and then later on (in a for loop, for instance) :

```
p_cell[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(cell*));
```

Comment: `cell *p_cell[height][width] = malloc(height*width*sizeof(cell*));` is not valid C, so cannot use that.  Maybe you are thinking `cell (*p_cell)[height][width] = malloc(height*width*sizeof(cell*));`?  Without knowing the application goals, the "best way" is not discernible without a broad discussion.

Comment: This `cell *p_cell[height][width];` already allocates an `height`x`width` sized array of pointers to `cell`, namely `p_cell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a 2D array of pointers, which can be declared as:

```
cell *p_cell[height][width];
```

To allocate each of these `cell *` pointers in `p_cell[i][j]`, you can do this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        p_cell[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(cell));
        /* check malloc */
        /* access using p_cell[i][j]->something */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I wanted. I had a huge amount of memory errors on Valgrind, reduced to no errors at all with your solution !

Answer (score 4):

```
data_type (*array) [width] = malloc( sizeof(data_type[height][width]) );
```

Now you can access the data using `arr[i][j]`

P.S:  2-D array should should be allocated as a contiguous chunk of memory, to get the best read write performance.

**Edit : ** As pointed out by chux in comment section that `array` is not a 2-D array, it's a pointer to 1-D array.

In order to make `array` as 2-D array, you need to declare it like this.

```
data_type (*array) [height][width] = malloc( sizeof(data_type[height][width]) );
```

Comment: `array` is not a 2-D array, but a pointer to a 1-D array.

Comment: *always*  is too strong a word when it comes to programming. There are no absolutes in what we do. Different platforms will have different constraints.

Comment: @chux : Right, It's a pointer to 1-D array. Now i have edited my answer.

Comment: Will this `data_type (*array) [height][width] = malloc( sizeof(data_type[height][width]) );` be a pointer to a 2D array or a 2D array of pointers ? I'm kind of lost with the C syntax sometimes.

Comment: @narfi : It will be a pointer to 2-D array. You need to access it using `(*array)[i][j]`.

Comment: @Shravan40 : Okay. Well I need a 2D array of pointers, and not a pointer to a 2D array. Sorry.

Comment: @narfi then simply `*array[height][width]`.

Comment: "*In order to make array as 2-D array, ...*"` still not correct as here `data_type (*array) [height][width]` `array` is a *pointer* to a 2D array. The array itself you get by doing `*array`.

Comment: To make a _pointer_ to a 2D array, `data_type (*array) [height][width]` is fine.  To allocate memory for that, code can simply use `array = malloc(sizeof *array);`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to allocate your 2D array:

```
cell *(*p_cell)[height][width] = malloc(sizeof(*p_cell));
```

`p_cell` is a pointer to a 2D array of pointers to `cell` objects. Item at coordinates `i`, `j` is retrieved with:

```
cell *p = (*p_cell)[i][j];
```

It is probably easier to make `p_cell` a pointer to an array of arrays:

```
cell *(*p_cell)[][width] = malloc(height * sizeof(*p_cell));
```

You would get the item at coordinates `i`, `j` with

```
cell *p = p_cell[i][j];
```

The above arrays are uninitialized, you would need to initialize them with pointers to existing `cell` objects or pointers to allocated `cell` objects.

If the 2D array is only used locally in your function and dimensions `width` and `height` are not too large, you can define the 2D array with local storage:

```
 cell *p_cell[height][width];
```

As `width` and `height` are dynamic values, static initialization is not available. You must initialize this array with a nested loop, like the allocated ones.

The question is: **Do you really need the element type to be a pointer to `cell`?**.  It is only useful if you are going to make some of these pointers point to the same object or have a null value, or point to `cell` objects referenced elsewhere.  Otherwise, it would be much easier to use an array of `cell` objects, either local to the function or allocated with `malloc()` or `calloc()`:

```
cell p_cell[][width] = calloc(sizeof(*p_cell), height);
```